# Setting parameter value for pdo with if/else

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'm trying to see if I can set a pdo parameter from a select query using if/else.

Say I have a query that I want a date value.

```
$values = [:date => $row['date']]
```

But I want to say "if date >= 180 days then use 180 for :date, else if <= 180 days use the number of days for :date"

So I want to check the date against 180 days. If it's over I want to use 180 but if less I want the number of days.

Is there a way to set one single parameter this way?

Comment: How can a date value (like '2018-10-06') be greater or less than 180 days? That makes no sense. You should show an example of a value for `$row['date']` and an example of a query you would use it in.

Comment: Sorry, if it's greater than or equal to 180 days ago from today

Comment: So if it's 2017-01-01, it's more than 180 days ago and I would want 180 for that. Just trying to get a number of days based on how many days ago it was but 180 is the cutoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$now = new DateTime('now');
$then = new DateTime($row['date']);
$diff = $now->diff($then);
$diff_days = min((int) $diff->format('%a'), 180) * (int) $diff->format('%R1');
$date = $now->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("$diff_days days"));
$values = ['date' => $date->format('Y-m-d')];
```

Comment: Just so I understand this is getting the number of days from now to date, and getting the minimum of 180 if greater or the number of days if less?

Comment: Yes, it uses `min()`.

Comment: You should try running this code, and echo the result of each step, until you understand how each step works. It would also be worthwhile to read about each function you don't know in the php documentation.